# Strange loop with size_t

Tags: c++, for-loop, size-t, type-promotion

I don't enter the loop using `size_t`. Why?
If I use `int` I enter the loop and the output is : `11, 11`

```
int main()
{
   int j = 11; 
   for (size_t i = 11; i > - 1; --j, i -=12)
   {

       std::cout << i << ", " << j << std::endl; 

   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you had compiled with warnings enabled (e.g. `gcc -Wall ...`) then your compiler would have warned you that `i > - 1` is always false and therefore your loop will never execute. Take-home message: **always compile with warnings enabled and take heed of any generated warnings!!!**.

Comment: As Bjarne says : "Use `int` until you have a reason not to." In your case, you don't have a reason not to.

Comment: Can u tell us your use case. Why u r using size_t and not int?

Comment: I use it when I do loops and it reprensents the index of an array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`size_t` is typically an unsigned value. In your for loop condition you're saying `i > -1`. Since `i` is an unsigned type the -1 is converted to this type, and will have the maximum value for that type.

Because of the promotion you're effectivly comparing 11 (the initial value of `i`) with the maximum value for `size_t` and the result is false, thus the loop is never entered.